# Get the latest non NaN values of timeseries for each identifier in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am stuck on how to get the latest non-NaN values of a DataFrame for unique identifiers. So I have a Pandas DataFrame with a column of IDs, values, and years, similar to this:

```
  |  ID | Values | Year
-------------------------
0 |  A  |  4.0   | 2016 
1 |  B  |  NaN   | 2016
2 |  C  |  NaN   | 2016
3 |  D  |  1.0   | 2016
4 |  A  |  2.0   | 2015
5 |  B  |  2.0   | 2015
6 |  C  |  1.0   | 2015
7 |  D  |  3.0   | 2015
8 |  A  |  2.0   | 2014
9 |  B  |  2.0   | 2014
10|  C  |  3.0   | 2014
11|  D  |  NaN   | 2014
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get a list of the latest (most recent) non-NaN values for each ID. So the list for this case should be:

```
[4.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

Which are the latest values for A, B, C, and D respectively (skipping over any NaNs). 
So far I've approached this by doing a pivot like this:

```
df.pivot(index = 'Year', columns = 'ID', values = 'Values')
```

So that I get:

```
ID   | A | B | C | D
----------------------
Year |   |   |   |   
2014 |2.0|2.0|3.0|NaN
2015 |2.0|2.0|1.0|3.0
2016 |4.0|NaN|Nan|1.0
```

And here I'm stuck- what would be the best way to get the most recent non-NaN values for each ID? Any suggestions using either the original DataFrame or the pivoted one would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another `groupby` option:

If the data is already sorted by `'Year'` descending, like in the example data:

```
df.groupby('ID')['Values'].first()
```

If the data isn't already sorted:

```
df.sort_values(by='Year').groupby('ID')['Values'].last()
```

The resulting output:

```
ID
A    4.0
B    2.0
C    1.0
D    1.0
```

Comment: @piRSquared: I didn't notice that it's already sorted in the example data.  If that's the expected format, no need to sort.

Answer (score 3):

You were sooo close. Use [`ffill()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df.pivot(index='Year',columns='ID',values='Values').ffill().values[-1]
```

Result:

```
array([ 4.,  2.,  1.,  1.])
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
df.ix[df.groupby('ID').Values.apply(lambda x: x.first_valid_index())]
```

[image]